# Convert string date to alarm

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to set alarms. i have times stored in a cvs file. They are in format hh:mm e.g 02:13. i WANT to set alarm for this time

Using following code

```
  SimpleDateFormat  dt = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm"); 
      dt.parse(str); // GET TIME HERE

NotificationManager manger = (NotificationManager) this.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.launcher, "Mosque Prayer Times", time);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getActivity(), 0, new Intent(this.getActivity(), AlarmReceiver.class), 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getActivity(), name, title, contentIntent);
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
        notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.trib.app.mosqueprayertimes/raw/adhan.mp3");
        manger.notify(id, notification);        
    }
```

I am finding it difficult how can i extract "time" from this date format and set it in my notification

Comment: Didn't `Date#getTime()` work?

Comment: i want to get current date with diff hours and min.

Comment: You can set the hours and minutes on the current date and then use `getTime` method. And also, using [joda-time](http://joda-time.sf.net) would be more than helpful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this....

```
 SimpleDateFormat  dt = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm"); 
     Date date=  dt.parse(str); // GET TIME HERE
    Calender cal=Calender.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    String hours=cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    String minutes=cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```